# Google maps not loading within js tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, dom

I am trying to make tabs using js to have more data on the site.

Please view: http://dev.ateo.dk/officelab-konferencecenter/

The two tabs at the top ("Billeder" and "kort") are made using js.

If i go into the tap called "kort", the google maps will not load completely - however if i right-click and choose "Inspect Element (Q)" using firefox,  the map suddenly loads.

Also, the map is not centered. on the specific location - the location is in the top left corner.

You may notice a blank square below the tab div. This is the exact same code as used within the js tab. If i comment out the  in js tab, the square which is blank, will work perfectly. So it somehow seems that the js tab combined with the js google maps are not working. Can this be the case, and if so, how is it fixed?

Below i am showing the code which will init the google maps and the taps on the page:

```
if($('body.single-konferencested').length > 0)
   {
       tabs();
   }

   if($('body.single-konferencested').length > 0)
   {
      $(document).ready(function() {
         function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(place_lat,place_lng);
            var mapOptions = {
               zoom: 9,
               center: myLatlng,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'), mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: myLatlng,
               map: map,
               clickable : true
            });

            var pinIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
               "http://dev.ateo.dk/wp-content/themes/ateo/img/pin_marker.png",
               null, /* size is determined at runtime */
               null, /* origin is 0,0 */
               null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
               new google.maps.Size(24, 40)
            ); 
            marker.setIcon(pinIcon);

            var content_string = '<div id="gmap_info">'+
                                    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+place_title+'</h3>'+
                                    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                                    '<p>'+place_address+'<br />'+place_city_zip+'</div>'+
                                 '</div>';

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: content_string
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
               infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
         }

         google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

      });
   }
```

This following is the html showing the DOM for the "Kort" tab:

```
<div class="tabContent" id="kort" style="padding: 5px 10px;">

    <h2>Kort</h2>
    <div id="gmap" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <h2>test</h2>
  </div>
```

Best regards
Patrick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the div in which the map is going to live is not visible on page load the map will not load correctly.  You should fire a resize once the div has come into view.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

You should bind this to the first click of the map tab.

It looks like the map is commented out of the second tab currently.  If you could uncomment it it would be easier to help you more specifically!

EDIT:
to bind the function once, try this:

```
var tab = jQuery('ul#tabs li')[1]
jQuery(tab).one('click', function(){
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

In order for the resize to work you will need access to the map variable from your init function.
It would also be easier to select the correct tab if you drop a class on it.  That would be more reliable then getting the 2nd li in the tabs ul.

EDIT 2:
try adding the click function in your initialize code.  Something similar to the following

```
var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 9,
   center: myLatlng,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'), mapOptions);

//add the code here, after the map variable has been instantiated
var tab = jQuery('ul#tabs li')[1]
jQuery(tab).one('click', function(){
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  //fire a center event after the resize, this is also useful
  // if bound to a window resize
  map.setCenter(myLatlng)
});
//end of new code

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: myLatlng,
   map: map,
   clickable : true
});
```

Comment: Hey,

Thansk for your help. Ofcourse, I am sorry, I though I had it back live again. It should now be visible again, and the error should be possible to view

Comment: Hi Wolffer,
I have now tried the solution you suggested, but without any luck.
I have posted the entire code for the tabs here http://pastebin.com/U9W310c2 , with your suggestion og the google maps resize within the showTab() - it is commented out in the code snippet.

What would you suggest I could try?

Comment: You don't have access to the map variable in the showTab function's scope.  I would suggest adding the code from my edit to your initialize function. I will post an edit above to demonstrate momentarily

Comment: Awesome wollfer, that works! However, i still have a problem centering the map. If you see the following code, where i have tried to fix the centering using your code: http://pastebin.com/6rjsT78C
The centering does not work on load, but if the page is refreshed, the map is centered. How can this be?

Comment: Try firing a re center after you fire the re size.  Because the map is initializing in a smaller space it centers itself on that area.  Once you resize it it doesnt know that you want it to re center as well until you tell it to.  So, use the following in the same click function as before: map.setCenter(myLatlng).  I have edited my post to show the new code as well.

Comment: That did it! Its weird that what you posted works, and the code i made didn't. In my head, it should do the same, but i guess not. Thanks alot wolffer! :)

Answer (score -1):

It can be solved easily by re-initialize the Google Map on Tab click.

```
$('#kort').click(function(e) {
    initialize();
    resetMap(map);
});
```

This simple solution has found from here - [How to Display Google Map Inside of a Hidden Div](http://www.codexworld.com/how-to-guides/display-google-map-inside-hidden-div/)