# Google Map is not working in my responsive tab

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My Google map is not working

I used this tab view

http://www.petelove.com/responsiveTabs/

My google map init() is:

```
var map;
function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: <?php echo $lat; ?>, lng: <?php echo $long; ?>},
            zoom: 3
});
```

When i run my google map in first tab it's working fine.
But when i load in second tab. I just get view only. NO MAP DISPLAYING.....

Comment: What errors are being displayed in your browser console?

Comment: `map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map')` this is most likely the problem if you have multiple maps with the same `id` on different tabs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps not loading within js tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559130/google-maps-not-loading-within-js-tab)

Comment: No I have only one map id, and i also do not use this id anywhere.       I think issue is in tabview jQuery....

Comment: No.  The issue is the map is hidden when it is initialized, you need to trigger the resize event once it has been displayed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postpone google maps initialisation until after bootstrap tab is shown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746698/postpone-google-maps-initialisation-until-after-bootstrap-tab-is-shown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked about a thousand times on this website. You should first search before asking again.

The key is that your map is hidden when initialized and therefore, you need to trigger a resize event **once the tab has been shown**.

`google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");`

Regarding the "tabs" library: choose a library that exposes **events**. This doesn't seem to be the case (or it is not documented) with the library you choose.

A quick example: [Bootstrap tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

This library exposes events:

> **Events**
>
> When showing a new tab, the events fire in the following order:
>
> **hide.bs.tab** (on the current active tab)
>
> **show.bs.tab** (on the to-be-shown tab)
>
> **hidden.bs.tab** (on the previous active tab, the same one as for the hide.bs.tab event)
>
> **shown.bs.tab** (on the newly-active just-shown tab, the same one as for the show.bs.tab event)

This way, you have full control over what happens with your tabs. You know when it's shown, hidden, etc.

So you could use something like:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  // Trigger map resize when tab is shown
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```

**Edit:**

If you need to reset the center, do it here:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  // Trigger map resize when tab is shown
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat; ?>, <?php echo $long; ?>));
});
```

Comment: Thank @MrUpsidown. All Working fine and map is also displaying now. But the only problem is that my marker is not displaying in center it's come in top left...I want it's in center......

Comment: Use `setCenter()` method with your center coords after you trigger the resize.

Comment: I used it already but it's now working, I think so,

var map1Options = {
    setCenter: {lat: <?php echo $lat; ?>, lng: <?php echo $long; ?>}
};

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with just CSS no JS needed:

```
   .tab-content > .tab-pane {
    display: block;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.tab-content > .active {
    display: block;
    height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keval, you need to trigger a resize when you display the map.

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event), you need to trigger a resize event like by
`google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");`

I created a fiddle by adding a tab to the demo page. I used the [attrchange jquery plugin](http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/) to listen to all the changes made to the `mapTab`, the tab that contains the Google Maps, just to make things simple.

Look at [this demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awaf1s9m/).

if you take out the listener, the maps would not show unless you click the Resize Map button. Hope this make things clear.

Comment: First, your answer is not formatted correctly. Second, your fiddle doesn't work.

Comment: huh.. that was weirded. it works sometimes. I just attached code from the two demo site with minimum modification

Comment: Thank to all.
All Working fine and map is also displaying now.

But the only problem is that my marker is not displaying in center
it's come in top left...I want it's in center.......

Comment: I think you also need to listen to the on map ready event and center your map to the center again.